# What (if anything) is the default functionality of the Tab key in Vim?

Tags: vim

I've been using Vim for a while now, and it's struck me as odd that an editor with such a focus on reducing keystrokes would leave a large, easily-reachable key such as Tab unbound.

[image: Tab key]

It's huge, it's right under my left pinky, and it's just *sitting there*. I feel a little silly even asking this question, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Is there some reason `<Tab>` is left without a predefined purpose in Normal and Visual modes -- perhaps some backward compatibility or edge case I'm not aware of? Should I just go ahead and make use of it in my own Vim configuration without fear, or is this a bad idea?

Comment: Why would binding a keystroke as per your preference be a bad idea? I'm not quite sure I get your question.

Comment: @GregHewgill It just strikes me as odd that at no point during Vi/Vim's long, long development history was Tab assigned to anything, when seemingly everything else on the keyboard has at *least* two uses depending on context. :)

Comment: The [keyboard on which vi was originally developed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg) did not have a Tab key.

Comment: Greg's comment is actually an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tab and CTRL-I are the same in Vim, and it's used to go through the jump list (opposite is CTRL-O).

From the documentation (`:help <tab>`):

```
<Tab>       or                  *CTRL-I* *<Tab>*
CTRL-I          Go to [count] newer cursor position in jump list
                (not a motion command).
                In a |quickfix-window| it takes you to the position of
                the error under the cursor.
                {not in Vi}
                {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}
```